# Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table?

Tags: c#, datatable

I keep getting this error all day today and I can't see how it is possible that it is happening? I am making a `DataTable`,and it has 7 columns , but when trying to add the array to the the table I get the error.

This is the code;

```
    public static void BulkEntityInsert<T>(this T entity, List<T> entities)
    {
        //give array lenght
        string[] columns = new string[7];          

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            int jj = 0;
            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entity))
            {
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                datecolumn.ColumnName = prop.Name == "Id" ? "ID" : prop.Name;
                datecolumn.DataType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
                columns[jj] = prop.Name == "Id" ? "ID" : prop.Name;                    
                jj++;
            }

            foreach (T t in entities)
            {
                // give the record array the same length as the columns variable
                object[] record = new object[columns.Length];
                
                int j = 0;
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(t))
                {
                    record[j] = prop.GetValue(t);
                    j++;
                }
                // Errror occurs here
                dataTable.Rows.Add(record);
            }
            // Save data to DB
            SqlBulkCopyInsert(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DataTable was not correctly made", ex.Message);
        }           
    }
```

Any help to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check what it really really really have enough columns. I don't see where/how you add columns.

Comment: What makes you so sure you have exactly 7 properties in T? Did you try to run a step by step debug to find the problem?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `dataTable`. Pretty sure its not filling it with what you think it is

Comment: @Sinatr, read the code, the error occurs when adding the array to the table,  I specified the column number with `columns` for this example to make it more understandable. The array has a lenght of 7.

Comment: @MasterYoda, of corse I am placing a breakpoint at `datatable` , nothing seems to out of place, hence this issue.

Comment: What has `string columns[]` to do with `dataTable`? I am looking for `dataTable.Columns` line and there is none.

Comment: @KyloRen Maybe you could tell us whats in the dataTable object before you call `SqlBulkCopyInsert(dataTable);` then?

Comment: @MasterYoda, 7 columns of varius types that are input into `record` object.

Comment: To be honest, your question could have need written better. However, I personally think that questions should only be downvoted for a few reasons: if they show complete lack of research or attempts to solve the problem, or if they are missing critical details, or stuff like that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, certainly, if I could have written the question better, I certainly would have. Please say how you would have done so?

Comment: First, the error text should be highlighted in the question itself (not only in the title). Second, You should have mentioned in the question itself in what row you get an error. Third, you should have written in the question itself that this is something that you are struggling with for some time now. Fourth, Sinatr's first comment was right on the spot - your conversation didn't make me feel like you understand what he/her have written, and also made me feel you are a bit resentful to him/her. If I was Sinatr, I might have been tempted to downvote this question just because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only one column and you are not adding it to the `DataTable`:

```
DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn();
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entity))
{
    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
    datecolumn.ColumnName = prop.Name == "Id" ? "ID" : prop.Name;
    datecolumn.DataType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
    columns[jj] = prop.Name == "Id" ? "ID" : prop.Name;                    
    jj++;
}
```

Instead you have to create them in the loop and then add them(last line in the loop body):

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entity))
{
    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn();
    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
    datecolumn.ColumnName = prop.Name == "Id" ? "ID" : prop.Name;
    datecolumn.DataType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
    columns[jj] = prop.Name == "Id" ? "ID" : prop.Name;                    
    jj++;

    dataTable.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
}
```